# Is there a way to align a item on the bottom of a LazyColumn?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list

I'm trying to implement a list with a button on its bottom, like the following:

[image]

Since I don't know how many items I would have on the list, I'm using a `LazyColumn`. The button on the bottom, should only be placed there if the list doesn't fill the entire screen, if it does, the button should be moved down and be the last item on the list.

Moving the button inside the `LazyColumn` like this:

```
LazyColumn(...) {
    items(items) { item -> ...}
    item { Button() } 
}
```

Gives the following:

[image]

I tried to add a `Spacer` with `fillMaxHeight()` modifier as an item between the two but it didn't change.

I also tried to add both the `LazyColumn` and the `Button` inside a column:

```
Column {
   LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
   ) {
        items(items) { item -> ...}
   }
   Button()
}
```

But this only anchors the button on the bottom as if the `Column` was a `LinearLayout`.

Considering this, would it be possible to align one of the `LazyColumn`'s items so it will always be on the bottom? Or, add some kind of space that fill the available area?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As stated in this [closed issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/198165609#comment3) it's possible to use `LazyColumn`'s `verticalArrangement` parameter to align the last item on the bottom by implementing `Arrangement.Vertical`:

```
LazyColumn(verticalArrangement = remember {
    object : Arrangement.Vertical {
        override fun Density.arrange(
            totalSize: Int,
            sizes: IntArray,
            outPositions: IntArray
        ) {
            var currentOffset = 0
            sizes.forEachIndexed { index, size -> 
                if (index == sizes.lastIndex) {
                    outPositions[index] = totalSize - size
                } else {
                    outPositions[index] = currentOffset
                    currentOffset += size
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

If you want to use it with `spacedBy` on the `verticalArrangement` parameter, as I was, you could use the following:

```
fun spacedByWithFooter(space: Dp) = object : Arrangement.Vertical {

    override val spacing = space

    override fun Density.arrange(
        totalSize: Int,
        sizes: IntArray,
        outPositions: IntArray,
    ) {
        if (sizes.isEmpty()) return
        val spacePx = space.roundToPx()

        var occupied = 0
        var lastSpace = 0

        sizes.forEachIndexed { index, size ->

            if (index == sizes.lastIndex) {
                outPositions[index] = totalSize - size
            } else {
                outPositions[index] = min(occupied, totalSize - size)
            }
            lastSpace = min(spacePx, totalSize - outPositions[index] - size)
            occupied = outPositions[index] + size + lastSpace
        }
        occupied -= lastSpace
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note that LazyColumn should be used with a fillMaxHeight modifier.

Answer (score 2):

We can wrap the button and **LazyColumn** with **Column** like this and ues verticalArrangement **SpaceBetween**.

we also can replace **SpaceBetween** with **SpaceAround**

```
   Column(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
) {
    LazyColumn(...) {

        items(items) { item -> ... }
    }
    Button()
}
```

I hope that has helped you.

Comment: Not sure if this entirely applies to what was need because, if the list is long enough, the button should be pushed "down the screen" and should only be shown as the last element of the list.

If you want the button fixed at the bottom, then I think this is the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

This was asked on the discord server and I came up with this:

```
LazyButtonTheme {
    // Change to a 10 to test the other case.
    val items = (0..100).toList()
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
    ) {
        if (listState.canScrollForward || listState.canScrollBackward) {
            // First layout (list is scrollable)
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                state = listState,
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
            ) {
                items(items.size + 1) {
                    if (it != items.lastIndex + 1) {
                        Text(
                            text = "$it"
                        )
                    } else {
                        Button(
                            onClick = { },
                            modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize()
                        ) {
                            Text(text = "Button")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Second layout (list is not scrollable)
            Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween) {
                LazyColumn(state = listState) {
                    items(items.size) {
                        Text(text = "$it")
                    }
                }

                Button(
                    onClick = { },
                    modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize()
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Button")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arthur Bertemes worked perfectly for my case.

I created a custom Lazy Column with that solution, just pass the lazy content to the *content* parameter:

```
/**
 * A [LazyColumn] that aligns the last item at the bottom of the screen
 * using a custom verticalArrangement function.
 */
@Composable
fun LazyColumnBottomAlign(
    contentPadding: PaddingValues,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    verticalPadding: Dp = 8.dp,
    horizontalPadding: Dp = 16.dp,
    content: LazyListScope.() -> Unit,
) {
    LazyColumn(
        verticalArrangement = remember {
            object : Arrangement.Vertical {
                override fun Density.arrange(
                    totalSize: Int,
                    sizes: IntArray,
                    outPositions: IntArray
                ) {
                    var currentOffset = 0

                    sizes.forEachIndexed { index, size ->
                        if (index == sizes.lastIndex) {
                            outPositions[index] = totalSize - size
                        } else {
                            outPositions[index] = currentOffset
                            currentOffset += size
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        modifier = modifier
            .padding(
                start = horizontalPadding,
                end = horizontalPadding,
                top = contentPadding.calculateTopPadding() + verticalPadding,
            )
            .fillMaxHeight(),
        content = content,
    )
}
```