# Hidden bottom item in LazyColumn - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list

I am trying to create a list of items with a hidden button at the bottom. By default the button is not visible on the screen.

If a user scrolls to the bottom of the list the button should appear like it is the last item of the list.

I created illustrations to better visualize the desired behaviour:

**Sketch 1: List with a few items**

[image]

**Sketch 2: List with a lot of items**

[image]

I already tried the solution for a similar problem (https://stackoverflow.com/a/69196765/11720296) and added extra offset but unfortunately it didn't work.

Does somebody have an idea how to create this behaviour?

Comment: This is a clean solution I've found so far: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66414579/7234479

Answer (score 0):

itemsIndexed will help in this case in following example I have used itemsIndexed in Lazycolumn it gives index which is visible to the user.
In this example I was trying to show some specific text only when first message is visible.

```
 LazyColumn() {
                itemsIndexed(tempListOfMessages) { index, localMessage ->
                    if (localMessage != null) {
                        SingleMessageView(
                            localMessageInfo = localMessage,
                            (index == 0)
                      )
                    }
                }  
            }
```

[image]

when scroll that text scroll with first item.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is similar to CollapsingToolbar, use [NestedScrollConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/input/nestedscroll/NestedScrollConnection)